# Wordrpress, ssh , servidor Google Cloud Developer que en ocasiones funciona correctamente

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress, ssh, google-cloud-platform

Estoy trabajando a través de una conexión SSH a un servidor que tiene instalado Wordpress en Google Cloud developer. Yo no configuré nada de la instalación en servidor, no tengo accesos para hacer modificaciones desde la cuenta de Google Cloud developer pues no es mía.
Había estado trabajando en la configuración de mi plantilla, pero de repente, se pone lenta la conexión y me saca una pantalla como esta:
[image: Error establishing a database connection]. Pasan unos minutos y aparentemente todo vuelve a la nomalidad y luego se repite el problema, pero el colmo es cuando intento consultar mi dominio y aparece una pantalla gris de que no se pudo establecer conexión, algo similar a cuando no tenemos conexión de internet.

Intento conectarme al servidor por Filezilla y php admin y no puedo.

Pasan unos minutos, y otra vez todo funciona con normalidad.
Contacte a quien  me dio los accesos para trabajar remotamente, pero me comenta que la DNS y el dominio funcionan correctamente.
¿Creen que se deba a que el servidor tiene recursos insuficientes para mi wp? ¿O que hay algo que revisar en las configuraciones de wp?
Gracias.

Comment: Es muy probable que este funcionando sobre una micro las cuales son limitadas a 1 núcleo y 600MB de RAm, lo cual genera estas caídas por ser compartida, La consola da recomendaciones de acuerdo a la carga que tenga la instancia para su incremento, pero si están haciendo uso de una capa gratuita, les van a cobrar por el uso que le den luego del incremento. Yo tenia el mismo problema con una instancia micro, luego del upgrade a una mayor todo bien, también la monte en la zona de latinoamerica por razones estratégicas de la app